# Linux kernel gives undefined reference for vmlinux but compiles the .o files

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, makefile, linux-device-driver

I have 2 driver files.

dr1.c

dr2.c

dr1.c does an EXPORT_SYMBOL(func1).

dr2.c uses that via a definition in dr1.h

Both the dr1 and dr2 are compiled and object files are created.
However, in th last stage of kernel compilation, I get an error
undefined reference for func1 in dr2 but the dr2 object file is created.

I do not understand why the linking is not happening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

dr1 was being compiled as a module
dr2 was being compiled into the kernel.

As a result the linking could not happen since dr1 is not part of vmlinux even though dr1 got compiled into a module without any error. I made dr2 into a module as well.

Also, I had to make sure that the kernel modules option is enabled in the config.

Answer (score 1):

Basically the linking doesn't happen because the address of `func1()` which is defined in `dr1.c` is unknown to `dr2.c`.

There are two solutions to this problem :

**1. Make the address known manually to the second file :**
In this case let us assume that the modules `dr1.c` and `dr2.c` are present in different directories and has got its own `Makefile`. Firstly, compile the `dr1` module. After its done, copy the `Modules.symvers` file to the directory containing `dr2.c` and then build the `dr2` module. The `Modules.symvers` basically contains the address of the "exported symbols", which, by copying it to the destination of the other module, you are making it "known" and thus finally the linking happens.

**2. Use a common Makefile for both the modules :**
Put both the `dr1.c` and `dr2.c` in the same directory and create a common kernel `Makefile` for it. Make the following entry in the Makefile :

`obj-m := dr1.o dr2.o`

When this is done, both the files will be compiled, produces a common `Modules.symvers` file and linked accordingly.

Hope this helped.

Comment: Thanks for the info on the procedure for manually linking it. I will use it in future.